# Cannot access the "manager" variable in Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, post-build

I'm trying to run a Groovy script as a post-build action. Unfortunately, I cannot use the `manager` variable. The following code:

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
def failedSummary = manager.createSummary('error.gif')
```

produces this error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager for
>   class: Script1

Please help.

Comment: this is most basic command, it works fine for me. Can you provide more information about jenkins and plugin version and platform. Also try similar command in jenkins script console as well. If you know docker, create docker images for me to debug.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot give more information as the task was dropped and I do not have access now to that machine.